# Appending to an R list using foreach is printing the list

Tags: r, foreach

I'm using a foreach loop to combine results in a list. The code below shows two loops one using for and one foreach. Both work fine but after executing the foreach version R prints the contents of the list to the console. Why is it doing this, is my syntax wrong?

Regards
Dave

```
inputs <- list(
     list()
    ,list()
    ,list()
    )

# prints list
results <- list()
foreach(input = inputs)  %do% {
  results[[length(results)+1]] <- input
}

# does not print list
results <- list()
for (i in 1: 10) {
  results[[length(results)+1]] <- inputs[[i]]
}
```

Comment: What is the function, `f()`?

Comment: That was just shorthand for doing something in the loop. I'll remove it for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you should use `foreach` is a bit different than the way you did. Take this example (which doesn't print the results):

```
require(foreach)
inputs <- list(list(), list(), list())
results <- foreach(input = inputs) %do% {
  one.result <- input
  return(one.result)
}
```

Comment: Got it, thanks! And I guess the return type from the iteration is a list of the inner function results which is convenient.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Instead of going `one.result <- input`, you put `one.result <- f(input)`,  which you had in your question. Think of a `foreach` as a bit like a function definition.